# Repeating arguments specified in options list

Tags: docopt

Is it possible to do something along the lines of:

```
Usage: 
  program submit [options]

Options:
  --user <email>            Users email address
  --documents <document>...  Documents to submit (can enter multiple)

submit --user Austin --documents doc1.txt --documents doc2.txt
```

This would then provide the following JSON:

```
{
  submit: True,
  --user: "Austin",
  --documents: ["doc1.txt", "doc2.txt"]
}
```

I'm aware that having repeating optional arguments is possible, I would just really prefer to specify so inside the options description rather than having to do:

```
Usage:
  program submit [--user <email>] [--documents <document>]...
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve this if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of a hack, but it should work:

```
"""
Usage:
  program submit [options]

Options:
  --user <email>            Users email address
  --documents <document>...  Documents to submit (can enter multiple)

submit --user Austin --documents doc1.txt --documents doc2.txt
"""

from docopt import docopt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = docopt(__doc__.replace('[options]',
                       '[options] [--documents <document>]...'))
    print(arguments)
```